# Slideshow specific images Tictail frameweok

Tags: slideshow

I know how to implement a slideshow in the "Tictail-framework". That tag does fetch images from products and shows them in a slideshow. Is there any way of viewing only a few of these products? (like nr 3, 9 and 15) in Tictal? I'm asking here, because Tictail's support isn't the best I've seen.

I know how to achieve this by using an external js, but it seems like unneccesary if the native slideshow - tag can be used for this. Here is the documentation: https://tictail.com/docs/templates

Answer (score 1):

You can get all images with

`{{#all_images}}
    <img src="{{url-500}}" alt="{{title}}">
{{/all_images}}`

with JS you could push all those images into an array and output your selection.